# AppFileTypes format in Desktop Bridge DesktopAppConverter

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

[The documentation for the DesktopAppConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#setup-conversion) shows that `-AppFileTypes` are to be specified as a comma-delimted list.

To be exact:

> **W_INVALID_FILE_TYPE_ASSOCIATION**
>   *A comma-separated list of file types which the application will be associated with (eg. ".txt, .doc", without the quotes).*

I'm trying to set two extensions (.md and .markdown) but no matter what I try the the converter gives an extension error:

> WARNING: DesktopAppConverter : warning 'W_INVALID_FILE_TYPE_ASSOCIATION': Rejected invalid application file type association(s): .md,.markdown

I've tried:
*   -AppFileTypes .md,.markdown  (which seems to be what the docs suggest)
*   -AppFileTypes ".md,.markdown"
*   -AppFileTypes ".md",".markdown"

None of these combinations work. Any idea on what the right format is?

FWIW a single extension works either quoted or unquoted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try **-AppFileTypes "'.md', '.markdown'"** The DAC documentation will be updated to reflect this. Thanks!